# Functions returning strings from other files

Tags: php, templates

I want to make a really simple template engine for my site, to make it easier to add new pages and edit other ones.

I have a `template.php` file and a variable of `$pageHeader`. Then in my `functions.php` file I have a function called `CallHeader()` with this code:

```
function CallHeader()
{
        echo $pageHeader;
}
```

The problem is this does not echo the contents of `$pageHeader` to the page. I have included `template.php` in `functions.php` using:

```
include("template.php");
```

I have also tried setting `$pageHeader` to be global but nothing works. I'm trying to call this from `index.php`, which has `functions.php` included. If I set the `CallHeader()` function like this:

```
function CallHeader()
{
        echo "test";
}
```

It works, and echo's "test" to the page on index.php

Any help as to why I can't echo the contents of `$pageHeader`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you tried this and it didn't work ?

```
function CallHeader()
{
    global $pageHeader;
    echo $pageHeader;
}
```

Comment: Hehe, i posted the exact same thing.. I'll remove mine then. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function CallHeader()
{
        echo $GLOBALS['pageHeader'];
}
```

global variables are a liability, not an asset.  you've been warned, don't come back whining that you've shot your foot.

Comment: Don't come running to me when you break your legs!